# Centering a title over two unordered lists in a dropdown mega menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I am looking to center a title over the top of two unordered lists. I am rather new to HTML,CSS and JS so my go-to is usually chat gpt or just google, but I cannot seem to find any examples of how to best do it, and chat gpt doesnt seem to have a clue what I want so i figured here was the best place to come.

As I have mentioned before, I am looking to center a title over two unordered lists. I have illustrated roughly what I want in this image:[Depiction of hover mega-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQZt.png)

I have all my current code in this codepen: [Codepen Code](https://codepen.io/DustyKrumples/pen/JjxrjBN?editors=0100) and I am hopeful you can help me.

I have tried positioning the header in multiple ways and changing how the lists are styled but I only seem to be able to make the header appear over the top of all the links, like this:[Long list of links under header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wk38.png), or have the header appear on the side in an individual box, like this:[Header in an individual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSsR.png) (notice the underline at the bottom of the box, because I'm using a border as my underline). I am doing the css and html only preferably. Here is the code if you don't like using codepen:

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="menu-main">
      <li class="Tab1"><a href="">Tab 01</a>
        <div class="menu-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 02</a>
        <div class="menu-mega">
          <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 03</a>
        
        <div class="menu-mega">
          
          <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
       
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Tab 04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #666666;
}
.menu-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
.menu-main li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  
}
.menu-main li:hover {
  background: gray;
}
.menu-sub {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.Tab1:hover .menu-sub,
.Tab2:hover .menu-mega
{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.menu-sub ul li {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-mega {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Also any improvements I could make to my code would be very much appreciated as I am still only 2 weeks into my web dev journey, and I'm always looking for how to improve! Thanks!

Comment: Start by spending some time making your HTML valid. This will give you a better base for applying your styling.

Comment: Could you give me a more specific response, what makes HTML code valid? As mentioned I am still new to HTML and CSS, so if you could clarify that would be great!

Comment: Learn to use https://validator.w3.org/nu/ regularly to check your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two separate lists displayed side by side, then you need to add a flex wrapper around them.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #666666;
}
.menu-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
.menu-main li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  
}
.menu-main li:hover {
  background: gray;
}
.menu-sub {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.Tab1:hover .menu-sub,
.Tab2:hover .menu-mega
{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.menu-sub ul li {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-mega {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.multi {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="menu-main">
      <li class="Tab1"><a href="">Tab 01</a>
        <div class="menu-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 02</a>
        <div class="menu-mega">
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 03</a>
        <div class="menu-mega">
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <div class="multi">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Tab 04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But if you want a single list which wraps automatically, you could just style the list with a `columns` rule.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #666666;
}
.menu-main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
.menu-main li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  
}
.menu-main li:hover {
  background: gray;
}
.menu-sub {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.Tab1:hover .menu-sub,
.Tab2:hover .menu-mega
{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.menu-sub ul li {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-mega {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity: 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #555555;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.multi {
  columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="menu-main">
      <li class="Tab1"><a href="">Tab 01</a>
        <div class="menu-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 02</a>
        <div class="menu-mega">
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Tab2"><a href="">Tab 03</a>
        <div class="menu-mega">
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <ul class="multi">
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 8</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 9</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 10</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Tab 04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, both ways. Many thanks for the clear on concise answer!